# While loop for a limited time (android)

Tags: android, eclipse

how do I implement a while loop for example ten seconds in eclipse? can someone help me? Have I to use a timer?

```
   Timer timer = new Timer(); 
   timer.schedule( new performClass(), 30000 );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't, in any language on any platform.  Busy waiting is a waste of processor cycles and battery power, and can keep background tasks from getting the processor.  The correct solution is to use a timer, or to spawn off a thread that sleeps for the required amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You want your while to execute x times during 10 seconds?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while( startTime + 10000 >  System.currentTimeMillis())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you objective is to pause execution for ten seconds you can try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html